# Send messages from rabbitMQ to PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, rabbitmq, mqtt, amqp

I know it is possible to send messages from PostgreSQL to RabbitMQ, but is it possible to send messages from RabbitMQ to PostgreSQL.

Right now i am feeding RabbitMQ throught the amqp plugin with some data coming from a raspberry-pi using MQTT.

So yeah, i was wondering if it was possible to run a script or install another plugin in the database or if i would need something between the two to process the messages and converting it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We need to write another service which will subscribe to rabbitmq message that service will insert the data into db. You can create service or any plugin which can consume messages from queue.